# Best Practices: IDE Code Color Scheme and Font

Tags: visual-studio, color-scheme

I was reading http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/01/27/asp-net-mvc-1-0-release-candidate-now-available.aspx and noticed a Fantastic color scheme used to illustrate their code in Visual Studio.

The white background is starting to hurt my eyes after long periods, but the black I find is also to abrasive.

Does anyone have a exported version of that color scheme, or in leiu, care to share their color schemes thwy find for a developer whic spends about 15 hours a day in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure which color scheme is the best - it pretty much depends on your individual preference. But take a look at the pages below for some schemes

- [Studio Styles](https://studiostyl.es/)
- [http://www.hanselman.com/blog/](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioProgrammerThemesGallery.aspx)
- [Is your IDE Hot or Not?](http://blog.codinghorror.com/is-your-ide-hot-or-not/)
- [Visual Studio Theme Generator](http://www.frickinsweet.com/tools/Theme.mvc.aspx)

Comment: I did "Is your IDE Hot or Not?" years ago and it is still one of the top referrers to my blog....

Comment: "Is your IDE Hot or Not?" seems to be down now.

Comment: "Is your IDE Hot or Not?" link fixed

Answer (score 5):

Try "Ruby Blue" from [this page](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioProgrammerThemesGallery.aspx).

Comment: I was just looking for it myself and luckily I just found it at http://gist.github.com/236449 it is hosted there by Dylan Thomas from http://dylandoesdigits.blogspot.com/2009/11/visual-studio-theme-ruby-blue-knockoff.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, Dave. I should add that the font that seems to work best for these darker colors--for me at least--is Monaco (http://www.webdevkungfu.com/textmate-envy-aka-monaco-font-for-windows/).

Comment: The folks over at Elegant code also have a version of the "Ruby Blue" theme that they blogged about at http://elegantcode.com/2009/11/22/visual-studio-color-scheme/

Comment: I'm also maintaining my own version, based on the emacs theme: http://bitbucket.org/jasulak/ruby-blue-visual-studio-theme/wiki/Home

Answer (score 1):

[Zenburn](http://slinky.imukuppi.org/zenburnpage/)

Oh and the VS2005 port by Jeff Atwood
[Zenburn VS2005](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000682.html)

Answer (score 0):

Consolas font works pretty good for me. It was designed for developers.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=22e69ae4-7e40-4807-8a86-b3d36fab68d3&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

A good font specially designed for Coding: http://input.fontbureau.com/